# Is there a way to make a dynamic condition for a SUMIF formula per an array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So pretty much I'm looking for the ability to make a dynamic condition for a SUMIF statement in which the condition is if the condition range equals one item or another in an array. The result of the SUMIF statement can be placed next to each condition range item.

The SUMIF condition should sum different cells based on the condition range for example equalling one item in an array or another item. I'm also sticking to a possible single dynamic condition instead of a multi-conditional statement due to the fact the array is updateable.

A practical example is shown below:

| Array |
| --- |
| condition_a |
| condition_b |

| Value | Condition | SUMIF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | condition_a | *30* |
| 30 | condition_b | *45* |
| 10 | condition_a | *30* |
| 15 | condition_b | *45* |

(In my situation both are tables. If that changes anything)

I'm new at stack overflow and the complex side of Excel so please go easy with me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `SUMIF` in Excel Table

[image]

**Without Condition (Array)**

```
=SUMIF([Condition],[@Condition],[Value])
```

**With Condition (Array)**

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH([@Condition],Table1[Array],0)),"Not in Array",
    SUMIF([Condition][@Condition][Value]))
```